# Sphinx Error when running searchd on windows (Failed to parse config file )

Tags: sphinx, config

I am installing sphinx for my database. i am following instructions from this article http://www.infotales.com/installing-sphinx-searc-on-windows/ , and this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8mDDEStuBes ,

Which look straight forward and simple. But i have been running into a problem. I am using the minimal config file, and have set up everything. When i run searchd --config c:/sphinx/bin/sphinx.conf, i get an error " failed to parse config file ", when i just run searchd in cmd , i get "no readable config file ". I don't know what to do, i have been looking around for a similar problem but usually people have this " failed to parse config file error " with other problems. Mine doesnt have any additional errors.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

here is my minimal config file (called it sphinx.conf ):

```
source users_info
{
    type                            = mysql

    sql_host                        = localhost
    sql_user                        = root
    sql_pass                        = root123
    sql_db                          = users
    sql_port                        = 3306                  



    sql_query                       = \
            SELECT \
                id, fullname,username                     
            FROM \
                    users_info;



    sql_query_info          = SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$id
}






index users_info
{
    source          = users_info
path            = C:/sphinx/data/users_info
docinfo         = extern
charset_type        = utf-8
}




indexer
{
mem_limit       = 32M
}


searchd
{
# listen            = 9312
listen          = 9306:mysql41
log         = C:/sphinx/log/searchd.log
query_log       = C:/sphinx/log/query.log
read_timeout        = 5
max_children        = 30
pid_file        = C:/sphinx/log/searchd.pid
max_matches     = 1000
seamless_rotate     = 1
preopen_indexes     = 1
unlink_old      = 1
workers         = threads # for RT to work
binlog_path     = C:/sphinx/data


}
```

Comment: You could try posting your config file, that's always a good place to start :)

Comment: Okay here is my minimal config file, i am only using the minimal config file, and i have deleted the large config file:

Comment: Ah that be why then, its empty! (edit your main post instead)

Comment: No , it's just i'm new here i'm learning the formatting, but there you go, this is my sphinx.conf in c:/sphinx/bin/

Answer (score 1):

Add a backslash after the mysql field declaration.

```
id, fullname,username
```

to

```
id, fullname,username  \
```

Comment: i did. Same problem, i doubt that it is a problem inside the config since it is not returning any errors except (failed to parse config file, and config file not readable ). So i'm guessing it is not reading the config file properly to start with. Do i need the large config file to be present even though i do not use it for configuration?

Comment: No you do not, when searchd fails to parse the config file, it should say why it cannot parse the config file. Something like `Error: Unknown XXX on Line YY \n Fatal: failed to parse config file`

Comment: it isn't giving me any errors, it's saying:
using config file 'c:/sphinx/bin/sphinx.conf' ...
FATAL: failed to parse config file 'c:/sphinx/bin/sphinx.conf'

The Config file has an extension (.in) on it, could this be the problem?

Comment: Yes that's your problem right there! the config file doesn't exist in that case. make the extension .conf

Comment: okay, this might sound noobish, but i renamed the file to sphinx.conf, but when i check it still has the extension .in, so it's still sphinx.conf.in, how can i change the extension in windows?

Comment: Thanks a lot lee, i have errors showing up now, i'll take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

**Check sphinx service installation.**

Write full path to your sphinx config.
For example:

**- invalid**

```
C:\Sphinx\bin\searchd --install --config mysphinx.conf --servicename MySphinxSearch
```

**+ valid**

```
C:\Sphinx\bin\searchd --install --config D:\Projects\mysite\mysphinx.conf --servicename MySphinxSearch
```